# How to assign and test for attributes on a rect in Pygame

Tags: python, attributes, pygame, collision, rect

This question requires no code, though it is an issue that I couldn't find the answer to elsewhere.

How might one test for collision of rects in Pygame only on an edge of the rect? I've looked at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html and feel like the answer's there, but that I just can't see it. This is very important, and I hope that this is an easy fix, and answerable.

```
if <rectname>.colliderect.bottom(<otherRect>):
    output = True
```

^ Does not work, but I suspect the answer might be similar. Thanks in advance if someone can help!

Comment: You want to know if `rect_a.bottom == rect_b.top` ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I tried coding exactly that but it treated the rects like they were infinitely wide so that if it went at the same layer of the screen as the other rect, the output would be triggered. I'm looking for a specific line segment on the screen...any more thoughts?

Comment: A `Rect` has four edges, so the edges of two of them could collide or "touch" in many ways. Please describe precisely which combinations you want to detect. Also, would you consider two horizontal edges colliding if they were drawn at two immediately adjacent x positions or only when they were exactly on top of one another?

Comment: I didn't consider that, no. I've already gotten the left and right collisions to work, but as far as the top and bottom of the block, the character just slides right through them. Any thoughts? (and thanks for all the help so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collision detection is a broad topic, especially if you want to know from which side a collection happened. (A common approach in plattformers is to do the collision detection twice, once for the horizontal and once for the vertical movement, like in [this example](http://www.nandnor.net/?p=64)).

If you just want to know if a `Rect` collides with the bottom of another `Rect`, the following example code should be a good starting point:

```
def collide_top(a, b):
    return a.top <= b.bottom <= a.bottom and (a.left <= b.left <= a.right or b.left <= a.left <= b.right)
def collide_bottom(a, b):
    return a.bottom >= b.top >= a.top and (a.left <= b.left <= a.right or b.left <= a.left <= b.right)
def collide_left(a, b):
    return a.left <= b.right <= a.right and (a.top <= b.top <= a.bottom or b.top <= a.top <= b.bottom)
def collide_right(a, b):
    return a.right >= b.left >= a.left and (a.top <= b.top <= a.bottom or b.top <= a.top <= b.bottom)

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

center = Rect((100, 100, 100, 100))
player = Rect((10, 0, 75, 75))

move = {K_UP:    ( 0, -1),
        K_DOWN:  ( 0,  1),
        K_LEFT:  (-1,  0),
        K_RIGHT: ( 1,  0)}

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0 ,0))
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for d in [m for (k, m) in move.items() if pressed[k]]:
      player.move_ip(*d)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (120, 0, 120), center, 3)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 200, 55), player, 2)
    # check if 'player' collides with the bottom of 'center'
    print collide_bottom(center, player)
    pygame.display.flip()
    if pygame.event.get(QUIT): break
    pygame.event.poll()
    clock.tick(60)
```

[image]

*(In this picture, `player` collides with the bottom and the left side of `center`, but not with the top or right side)*

Some further questions:

What happens when one rect is fully inside another one? Does it collide with all edges or none in this case?

---

In response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821463/how-to-assign-and-test-for-attributes-on-a-rect-in-pygame/17828204?noredirect=1#comment26032022_17828204):

You can simply change the collision check to

```
def collide_top(a, b):
    return a.top == b.bottom and (a.left <= b.left <= a.right or b.left <= a.left <= b.right)
def collide_bottom(a, b):
    return a.bottom == b.top and (a.left <= b.left <= a.right or b.left <= a.left <= b.right)
def collide_left(a, b):
    return a.left == b.right and (a.top <= b.top <= a.bottom or b.top <= a.top <= b.bottom)
def collide_right(a, b):
    return a.right == b.left and (a.top <= b.top <= a.bottom or b.top <= a.top <= b.bottom)
```

Comment: Well, the plan is that the edges touch each other but do not overlap at all. This is nice of you to put this, but I'm looking for something more along the lines of @monkey: rect1.bottom==rect2.bottom. I like the idea of testing for horizontal AND vertical lines, so I can try incorporating that into my design to prevent the problem from happening which I described in response to him, but we'll see. Do you have any thoughts on what he was talking about though? With the .bottom and .top?

And yes, I'm aiming at a platformer type game.

Comment: @user2597443 See my edit. It's just a simply change to test if the edges touch each other, without overlapping.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! I think I'll be able to work with this, but if I have some problems with this, I'll post something. Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I deleted that post because I could get the code--nonetheless. It turns out only the sides are working for me and not the top and bottom...any thoughts?

Comment: @user2597443 In which way are they not working? As my example shows, it works fine. Maybe your problems are related to movement and the fact that the `top` of one `Rect` and the `bottom` of another one never match exactly?

Comment: Err, no I don't think so. Here's the supposed chunk of code that's not working (supposed to stop character from falling through ledge):

        if collide_bottom(characterRect,ledge1):
        characterRect.y=characterRect.y - 1